# Redirect www.example.com to www.example.com/home/

Tags: apache-2.2, django

I'm currently writing a Django website, and I've got a bunch of flat pages that are my basic website. What I want is www.example.com/home to be the main website flat page, but when people go to www.example.com it redirects to www.example.com/home. I'm sure this is a simple thing, but I just had trouble coming up with the correct search terms.

A few possible solutions that I've had a look into:

1. **mod_rewrite** for apache. Seems a little overkill for this.
2. **DNS redirect**. Once again seems ok if going from www.here.com to www.example.com but not for what I want.
3. **django.contrib.redirects** seems like it will do what I want, but again seems like it's for some other reason.
4. Is there something I can do in my virtual hosts file?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 9.04, apache 2.2 and Django 1.1 with wsgi.

Cheers,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite is a perfect fit for this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /home/ [R]
```

Comment: Does the mod_rewite go in the virualhosts file?

Comment: yes. and now some more to fill the comment.

Comment: +1 for the good answer. But gave the actual answer because of performance reasons to Mathieu.

Comment: actually this worked first time. And i wasnt sure where to put the index.html considering the wsgi script. So I gave you the answer instead

Answer (score 1):

you can also put a static index.html page with this html code in the head section of this nearly empty html page:

> META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=/home">

You will need to add a "<" at the beginning of course, it's blocked if i put it here

Comment: How performant is this compared to mod_rewrite. I like the simplicity tho.

Comment: this is clearly what will consume the less resource. It involves the minimum: send static content to client.
I think that mod_rewrite will send a 302 directly, so users won't really  notice. With this static page, they will see a white page for a second or two

Comment: And also i guess if you host the static content on nginx or something it will be faster/ it will also be cached?

Comment: page can be cached, more over if you explicitely  add the expire meta tag inside the page

Comment: Do you know if this would work with wsgi? because I dont really know where the index.html would go in this case?

Comment: i don't know this one. It should be in root of your DocumentRoot. Try to get it from your browser. If it doesn't work, the apache error log file will complain about a non existing file with the tried path. Hard way to find where the file should be

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect/2080377#2080377) about how to do redirects in Django directly in `urls.py`..

Comment: Any Idea on how performant this is compared to the other answers?

Comment: @Mark: No, sorry.